# How to check checkboxes in caml query?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, caml

In SharePoint 2010 client object model (JavaScript), I am using this caml query to download list items.

There is a column called `'Office'` and in it, there are several check boxes (i.e. its a multi-select field). I am looking to get the items where the checkbox in the `Office` field, that has the name `'Toronto'` is checked. I don't want to consider the values of the other checkboxes in the `Office` field. This query below is not working though because I am getting 0 items, when I know I should be getting more.

```
var camlquerystring = "
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Office'/>
<Value Type='Boolean'>
Toronto
</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
</View>";
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change `<Value Type='Boolean'>` to `<Value Type='Text'>` or `<Value Type='MultiChoice'>`.

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/b20b1945-4b73-4320-8666-957650dc6a20

Answer (score -1):

CAML and Querying Boolean Fields
By Erkka PeltoniemiFebruary 22 201016 comments
Today I had some trouble trying to filter out items by a field of type Boolean. I have a custom content type definition which has a FieldRef to a Field:

```
  <Field
   Type="Boolean"
   DisplayName="IsHeadlineDisplayName"
   Description="IsHeadlineDescription"
   Required="TRUE"
   Group="SharepointBluesCustomFields"
   ID="{3166A1DF-3EE9-4757-8344-B65BC2482261}"
   SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/3.0"
   StaticName="IsHeadline"
   Name="IsHeadline" />
```

As my first shot at trying to filter out the records I wrote this CAML query:

```
<Where>

        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='IsHeadline' />
          <Value Type='Boolean'>TRUE</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
```

As a new comer to the world of Sharepoint development I expected this query to return all of the records which have a IsHeadLine field set to true, yet when I fired the query with SPList.GetItems method the engine would happily return all of the records regardless of their IsHeadline field's value. As Sharepoint doesn't seem to be too consistent on case sensitivity I first thought this was a case sensitivity issue but the query kept returning the same results regardless of how I wrote my parameter.

Turns out you can treat the Sharepoint Boolean fields much the same way as you may have gotten used to doing with T-SQL. With Integer types. 1 representing positive and 0 a negative value.

So I modified my CAML query a bit:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='IsHeadline' />
      <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
```

This solved my problem and now the engine is finally returning me the proper records.

this was sourced from http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/02/22/caml-and-querying-boolean-fields/

Comment: But this is when your field has 1 checkbox. But my field called `Office` has 6 checkboxes, one of them is called `Toronto`. How can I write the caml query to get the items where the `Toronto` checkbox in the `Office` field is checked?

Comment: It looks like you would need to return just the Office field itself and then iterate over the values to determine which ones are true or false.. Looks like this is not supported

Comment: Queries for multi-value lookup fields and users
Because multi-value lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes element or NotIncludes element is not supported). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yes there is
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/b20b1945-4b73-4320-8666-957650dc6a20

Comment: Well there you go!